# window.location.href not working after Response.End()

Tags: javascript, jquery, httpmodule, ihttpmodule

I tried all the answers from other similar questions but did not solve my problem.

I have an AJAX call to a HttpModule. Inside the HttpModule, I ended the request using

```
Response.End()
```

Then, on the .done() on AJAX, I did a redirect

```
window.location.href = <valid location>;
```

To verify that window.location.href works on the browser, I tested it on a blank browser and it worked!

There may be something that prevented the window.location.href from executing after the premature end of the Response. Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Response.End is blocking the redirection in Javascript.

I have tried using the suggested fixes from other threads (e.g. SessionTimeout and adding return false after the redirect), but both did not work.

As a work-around, instead of using window.location.href, I did a window.location.reload(). This fixed my problem.

I still welcome ideas and suggestions.

Comment: It sounds like the URL you were trying to load was the same one the user is already on. That doesn't always work and yes, you'd have to use `window.location.reload()` in that case.

Comment: In which case...what's the point of using JS at all for this?